# scroll an element on the page along with a normal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 blocks on the page, on the middle block there is a vertical line and on this line there is an element with class `circle`

The question is, is it possible to make this circle scroll across the page along with the usual scroll?

That is, the circle itself should not be a scroll, it should just move up and down the page, along with the standard scroll

And also the line on which this circle has a gradient, and also it is necessary that the color of the circle changes along the gradient line

I tried somehow to bind this element to the scroll through javascript, but nothing sensible came out

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center/2px 80% no-repeat;
  
  .circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 2px orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: calc(50% - 8px);
  }
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: Scroll (move?) the circle? Where? In which direction? In relation to what? What is its purpose of scrolling with the page? Can you share more details on the desired result? PS... you forgot to add some JS you're having issues with

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it should move down the line and up the line, just like a regular scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the moving, you can simply use CSS `position: sticky` with `bottom: 50%;`

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.block1 {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center bottom / 2px 100% no-repeat;
}

.circle {
  position: sticky;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text<p style="height: 60vh">Emulate some dynamic height text</p>End</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

For changing the color of the circle, some JavaScript would be needed in order to determine the circle offset relative to its parent - and apply that calculated `delta` to the HSL (Hue) degrees of `hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)`

PS: don't forget to add `position: relative;` to its parent.

```js
// This is a proof of concept.
// Don't use in production before you implement the 
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver

const elsCircle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

const changeCircleColorScroll = (elCircle) => {
  const y = elCircle.offsetTop;
  const parentHeight = elCircle.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const delta = y / parentHeight;
  const hue = Math.floor(42 - delta * 42);
  elCircle.style.borderColor = `hsl(${hue}, 80%, 50%)`
};

addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  elsCircle.forEach(changeCircleColorScroll);
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.block1 {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orange) center bottom / 2px 100% no-repeat;
}

.circle {
  position: sticky;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 text">Text<p style="height: 60vh">Emulate some dynamic height text</p>End</div>
    <div class="col-6 text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, I have a problem, if I remove the fixed height, then everything will stop working